# pyomo dae differential equation is applying ode "retroactively"

Tags: differential-equations, pyomo

Sorry for the awkward choice of words in the title.

The thing is: I have a concrete model with a continuous set variable to express time and a very simple ode, where the derivative of a variable, let's call it dadt, equals the difference between two other variables b and c which are not dependent on a (in other words, a is just the difference of b and c multiplied by time). Unfortunately, it seems that the programm applies the intgration backwards meaning that if dadt is,say, 20 at time=20s, then a increases by 20*dadt between 0s and 20s. This way, the differential equation constraint does not really apply to time=0s and therefore renders the optimization useless. 
Is it intended this way or did I make a mistake along the way? I should add the Lagrange-Radau collocation. Is it the this kind of collocation's standard way of interpreting the direction of the integration, meaning "backward"?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question. Could you post the code for your entire model, including the discretization, and explain the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: The code looks like this:                                                                       def constraint_26_rule(Model,i):
    return Model.dAdt[i]==Model.B[i]-Model.C[i]  Model.constraint26=Constraint(Model.t, rule=constraint_26_rule)              The discretization is implemented as follows:                                 discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.collocation')
    discretizer. apply_to(Model, nfe=parttime, ncp=1, scheme= 'LAGRANGE-RADAU')

Comment: I managed a workaround: def constraint_26_rule(Model,i):
        if i==parttime*3600:
            return Model.A[i]==Model.A[i]
        return Model.A[i+3600]==(Model.B[i]  - Model.FC[i])*3600
    Model.constraint26=Constraint(Model.t, rule=constraint_26_rule)
   However, I find this very ugly. Obviously, there is a "forward" and "backward" option for finite differences, so I was wondering if one can tell the discretizer to apply the lagrange-radau collocation "forward", too.

Comment: There is no "forward" option for lagrange-radau collocation. However, I don't see how this is a problem as all of the equations are solved simultaneously and you have the flexibility to specify either initial or final boundary conditions. What boundary conditions are you setting and what are you trying to optimize?

Comment: The problem actually is that the value for A increases by dAdt[3600] between time points 0s and 3600s. Since it is vital for the validity of the optimization to not break the lower bounds of A and it actually does in this period because dAdt[0] is higly negative, the optimization is useless this way.

Comment: Anyway, above workaround works pretty well, I just wanted to be sure that there is no way of  having a "forward" collocation since the workaround actually is in effect a "forward" finite difference method with all its downsides.

Comment: The problem with this workaround is that if one increases the number of collocation points, the indces are not at equal distance from each other. Is there a possibility to access the value of the next index? I tried to use the .index() function by writing: Model.t.index(i) e.g.  def constraint_26_rule(Model,i): return Model.A[Model.t(Model.t.index(i)+1)]==Model.B[i]-Model.C[i] Model.constraint26=Constraint(Model.t, rule=constraint_26_rule). However, I get the error message that index() only takes one argument, but two are given.

Comment: You can use the next(i) and prev(i) methods on the ContinuousSet to get the neighboring points. For example, Model.A[model.t.next(i)] == Model.B[i]. WARNING: This will only work consistently if you declare the constraint AFTER applying a discretization

Comment: @Bethany Nicholson : It works. (I would say "Thank you a lot!!!", but then, this site does not approve of that...). Maybe you post it as an answer and I mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the next(i) and prev(i) methods on the ContinuousSet to get the neighboring points. For example,

```
Model.A[model.t.next(i)] == Model.B[i]
```

WARNING: This will only work consistently if you declare the constraint AFTER applying a discretization